# How to pass a value from Perl program going to a WebServer that uses PHP?

Tags: php, perl

I want to know how Perl programmers pass a GET/POST value to php program

Perl Program(PerlVALUE) ---->>>> PHP(convert to GET/POST ---->>>> http://www.example.com?name=PerlVALUE&lastname=PerlVALUE

Anyone knows how to do it?...thank you...

Answer (score 4):

This is one way to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new();

$agent->post("http://www.example.com", {
    name => "PerlVALUE",
    lastname => "PerlVALUE"
});
```